# how to show title as url instead of id in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

in controller

```
 public function show($id)
 {

 }
```

in route

```
Route::get('post/{id}','PostController@show');
```

how to show title as url instead of id ? and is it possible to change only url as title otherwise we need to specify unique title in database table ?

Answer (score 1):

in controller

```
public function show($title) // For the understanding
 {

 }
```

in route

```
Route::get('post/{title}','PostController@show');
```

in view just use the `title` instead of `id`.

Comment: @bos3.thank you for the answer.but in that situation we need to use unique slug right . is there way only to show title in url ?

Comment: Yes. Use slug instead of title and make them unique.

Answer (score 1):

in controller

```
 public function show( $title = "basic", $id = 0 ) 
 {

 }
```

in route

```
Route::get('post/{title}-{id}','PostController@show')->where("id", "[0-9]+");  // id should be integer
```

in view just add the `title` leftside `id`.

By the way you don't need unique slug.

Answer (score 1):

No mater what you use in `Route`. It could be `{id}` or `{title}` or `{slug}` or anything. It's like a wild card. The important this is what you are passing through the wild card. It depends on your blade file.

**Your blade file should looks like this:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Other</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($datas as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ action('PostController@show',[$data->id]) }}">{{ $data->title }}</a></td> 
        <!-- by using [$data->id] as a second parameter when a user click on title it will view the show page with data of the same row from database -->
        <td>{{ $data->other }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('post/{id}','PostController@show');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrfail($id);
    return view('folder.fileName',compact($post));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple! Just add this to your model class:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()   
{
return '[your-column-name-here]';
}
```

Laravel uses this function getRouteKeyName() to to what the name indicates:)